# Can I disable rubber band inertial scrolling in UIScrollView

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode, uiscrollview

I have a scroll view, it scrolls my view. If I scroll far up or far down, it shows white space. I believe this is known as the rubber band effect or inertial scrolling. Is there a documented or allowed way I can disable this?

Comment: If the problem is the white showing, you can change the UIScrollView back view color

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Set scrollbar's bounce property false/no. It will not bounce after that.

`self.scrollView.bounces = NO;`

Answer (score 4):

Use this:

```
self.scrollView.bounces = NO;
```

Answer (score 4):

Yeah. In interface-builder or Storyboards, just select the UIScrollView and un-check the 'bounces' property.

In code:

```
self.scrollView.bounces = NO;
```

Answer (score 4):

Check for `UIScrollView` **bounces** property. It is like on/off property for such behaviour.

Answer (score 3):

```
self.yourScrollView.bounces = NO;
```